# MobaXterm install process starts when i quit

Tags: winscp, mobaxterm

I have both mobaXterm and WinScp installed. Every time i close mobaXterm i get this message

[image: winscp install window]

When i try to cancel the process trys to install anyway. I can only stop the process by killing mobaxterm

Comment: Have you tried to provide a path to the file it’s looking for?

Answer (score -1):

Turns out it was an old version of winscp that kept trying to install. I ran the [microsoft installer cleanup](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17588/windows-fix-problems-that-block-programs-being-installed-or-removed) software, witch fixed the problems